# Listview как добавить разделитель снизу последнего элемента?

Tags: android, listview

Собственно, вопрос довольно-таки простой (для вас) наверное. Но мои попытки не увенчались успехом. В общем, есть фрагмент с ListView. Сам разделитель между строками я добавил, но еще нужно добавить его в самый конец. Попробовал прописать свойство `android:footerDividersEnabled="true"`, и ничего не произошло. Вот код фрагмента:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/bg_main">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/setting_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:divider="@color/color_main"
        android:footerDividersEnabled="true">
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Наведите на мысль, как это реализовать. А то я уже даже хотел пустую строку в список добавить))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня была подобная ситуация с моим `ListView`, я могу вам посоветовать во-первых заменить `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` на `android:layout_height="match_parent"`  и дальше попробуйте все-таки добавить ваш `divider`. Можно еще попробовать добавить пустой элемент в возможно у вас будет добавляться разделительная черта перед этим элементом. Например пустой и прозрачный `textView`. Вот [ссылка](https://medium.com/@szholdiyarov/how-to-add-divider-to-list-and-recycler-views-858344450401) по вашей теме может вам поможет чем-то. 
И вот [ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14199274/separator-divider-after-last-item-of-listview) на enSO с подобной ситуацией.
Надеюсь что я помог хоть чем-то в решении вашей проблемы.

Comment: Век живи - век учись!! заменил android:layout_height="wrap_content" на android:layout_height="match_parent", и теперь все как надо. спасибо!

Comment: поздравляю :)))

Comment: но если честно, мне такое поведение не понятно. Wrap_content выравнивает по содержимому, но получается, что одновременно отменяет действие некоторых свойств.

Comment: не отменяет я думаю а просто ограничивает, вот например в вашей ситуации он не дал создать разделитель, по возможности нужно я думаю давать виджету немного свободы

Comment: @Snuf, так ведь содержимое `ListView` не умещается в экран и Вы просто не видите этот разделитель. Для элементов с прокруткой нельзя использовать `wrap_content` в направлении прокрутки - это противоречит их предназначению.

Comment: Эмм..у меня там всего 4 элемента в списке было. Я думал, что они по-любому влезут в экран. Теперь все стало на свои места